# Save pdf directly to file using jspdf

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf, firefox-addon, jspdf

My script is a Firefox addon so has access to sensitive code like access to filesystem etc.
I display a `Panel` populated with `html` content, I could easily send input to the addon code using `postMessage`
When I run the code below a `pdf` is generated and a download prompt is shown so i can select directory to place file, but I'd like to save the file using javascript directly to a file in background without the download prompt showing.
Something like: `doc.saveToFile("/path/to/file") // custom method in my addon code`
Would this be possible using the `jsPDF` object?

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jspdf.source.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        Hey
        <script>
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello bob');
        doc.save('test.pdf');
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can this be also done in `chrome`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work on your Firefox add-on code:

```
const { OS } = require("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm");

var pathToFile = OS.Path.join("path", "to", "file.pdf");

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello bob');

var ab = doc.output('arraybuffer');
var u8 = new Uint8Array(ab);

OS.File.writeAtomic(pathToFile, u8).then(
   function()
   {
       alert('File written!');
   },
   function(e)
   {
       alert('Error ' + e);
   }
);
```

If you aren't using the Add-On SDK, but rather a normal extension, replace the first line with:

```
const { OS } = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm", {});
```

Check this out for further info on OS.File: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread

Answer (score 0):

But why you don't wanna use your add-on? I think that you don't be able to access the filesystem or things like that, with jsPDF or pdf.js (http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/, which is a mozilla project), you will be able to print something that is being displayed on the window, but not sure if you can access some local files.

Comment: Not sure what your suggesting. Addon sdk has access to local file system, so I'd like to be able to say `doc.saveToFile("/path/to/file")` in addon code.

Comment: sorry I thought that you wanted to change your add-on for pdf.js. Not sure if you will be able to make it. Anyway, the problem with these experimental libraries is that they are not going to work on all the browsers, you need support for example also in IE?

Comment: No, I'm making a `Firefox` addon. Do not need to support any other browsers.