# How to write and save file directly using JSPDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, jspdf

Is there a way to save `jsPDF` **DIRECTLY** into a **specific location** using `chrome`?

My current implementation of the `jspdf` code (`doc.save`) still asks for a location to save the `pdf`.

Could you guys guide me on a **workaround** to write the `pdf` directly when using chrome?

I've only seen a solution but it is for `firefox`: [Save pdf directly to file using jspdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233344/save-pdf-directly-to-file-using-jspdf)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see you cant.

It´s depending on what the user selects in the chrome options

(chrome://settings -> downloads -> checkbox ask where to save ...)

any workaround would be some serious security flaw

Comment: I forgot to include that it is a `desktop application` built using `Electron JS`. Would there be any workarounds on `Electron`?